# How to view runtime warnings in PyCharm when running tests using pytest?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, warnings

When running tests in PyCharm 2022.3.2 (Professional Edition) using pytest (6.2.4) and Python 3.9 I get the following result in the PyCharm console window:

> D:\cenv\python.exe "D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/PyCharm 2022.3.2/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path D:\tests\test_k.py
> Testing started at 6:49 PM ...
> Launching pytest with arguments D:\tests\test_k.py --no-header --no-summary -q in D:\tests
>
> ============================= test session starts =============================
> collecting ... collected 5 items
>
> test_k.py::test_init
> test_k.py::test_1
> test_k.py::test_2
> test_k.py::test_3
> test_k.py::test_4
>
> ======================= 5 passed, 278 warnings in 4.50s =======================
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> PASSED          [ 20%]PASSED [ 40%]PASSED [ 60%]PASSED [ 80%]PASSED [100%]

So the actual warnings don't show. Only the number of warnings (278) is shown.

I tried:

1. selecting: Pytest: do not add "--no-header --no-summary -q" in advanced settings
2. Setting Additional arguments to -Wall in the Run/Debug configurations window
3. Setting Interpreter options to -Wall in the Run/Debug configurations window

and all permutations, all to no avail. Is there a way to show all runtime warnings when running tests using pytest in PyCharm in the PyCharm Console window?

EDIT:

@Override12

When I select do not add "--no-header --no-summary -q" in advanced settings I get the following output:

> D:\Projects\S\SHARK\development_SCE\cenv\python.exe "D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/PyCharm 2020.3.4/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path D:\Projects\S\SHARK\development_SCE\cenv\Lib\site-packages\vistrails-3.5.0rc0-py3.9.egg\vistrails\packages\SHARK\analysis\tests\test_fairing_1_plus_k.py -- --jb-show-summary
> Testing started at 10:07 AM ...
> Launching pytest with arguments D:\Projects\S\SHARK\development_SCE\cenv\Lib\site-packages\vistrails-3.5.0rc0-py3.9.egg\vistrails\packages\SHARK\analysis\tests\test_fairing_1_plus_k.py in D:\Projects\S\SHARK\development_SCE\cenv\Lib\site-packages\vistrails-3.5.0rc0-py3.9.egg\vistrails\packages
>
> ============================= test session starts =============================
> platform win32 -- Python 3.9.7, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- D:\Projects\S\SHARK\development_SCE\cenv\python.exe
> cachedir: .pytest_cache
> rootdir: D:\Projects\S\SHARK\development_SCE\cenv\Lib\site-packages\vistrails-3.5.0rc0-py3.9.egg\vistrails\packages
> plugins: pytest_check-1.0.5
> collecting ... collected 5 items
>
> SHARK/analysis/tests/test_fairing_1_plus_k.py::test_init
> SHARK/analysis/tests/test_fairing_1_plus_k.py::test_without_1_k_fairing
> SHARK/analysis/tests/test_fairing_1_plus_k.py::test_1_k_fairing_given
> SHARK/analysis/tests/test_fairing_1_plus_k.py::test_without_1_k_fairing_only_3_values_under_threshold
> SHARK/analysis/tests/test_fairing_1_plus_k.py::test_1_k_fairing_given_only_3_values_under_threshold
>
> ============================== warnings summary ===============================
> ......\pyreadline\py3k_compat.py:8
> D:\Projects\S\SHARK\development_SCE\cenv\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\py3k_compat.py:8: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
> return isinstance(x, collections.Callable)
>
> ......\nose\importer.py:12
> D:\Projects\S\SHARK\development_SCE\cenv\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py:12: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
> from imp import find_module, load_module, acquire_lock, release_lock
>
> SHARK/analysis/tests/test_fairing_1_plus_k.py: 276 warnings
> D:\Projects\S\SHARK\development_SCE\cenv\lib\site-packages\pymarin\objects\key.py:1101: UserWarning: siUnits is deprecated, use siUnit
> warnings.warn('siUnits is deprecated, use siUnit')
>
> -- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
> ======================= 5 passed, 278 warnings in 5.79s =======================
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> PASSED          [ 20%]PASSED [ 40%]PASSED [ 60%]PASSED [ 80%]PASSED [100%]

So 4 warnings are displayed. However I would like to see all 278 warnings.

When I run pytest from the command line outside PyCharm I get the same result. So it seems to be a pytest problem and it seems that it has nothing to do with PyCharm.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is due to --no-summary argument added by PyCharm. Can you try checking it again from advanced settings and post the output ? Your current output suggests you still have those arguments appended to your pytest command

Comment: @ override12 I edited the question with the output of the 'do not add "--no-header --no-summary -q" in advanced settings' case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is a combination of two things:

1. Setting 'do not add "--no-header --no-summary -q"' in advanced settings as @Override12 suggested.
2. When the same warning is issued multiple times, only the first time is displayed. In my case solving the first warning reduced the number of warnings from 278 to 2.

Comment: Useful, but keep in mind that PyCharm will seemingly ignore that setting if you *re*run a test from the run panel. *Sigh.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also try adding [verbosity](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/output.html) or [collect warnings](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/capture-warnings.html) in a programatic way, by changing how you execute the tests.

Comment: I tried verbosity and collect warnings. Unfortunately they both do not change the output. But maybe I am doing it the wrong way?